# How to remove all adjacent newlines and whitespaces in Javascript and replace them with single newline?

Tags: javascript, regex, newline, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Let's say I have string like this:

```
Hello,     \n\r  \n\n\n \n      World \n\n     !
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
Hello,
World
!
```

So anytime there are two or more adjacent newline characters or newline character adjacent to single or more whitespaces, it should replace them with single newline character.

How to achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: I feel like this definitely has a duplicate somewhere, but anyway `[\r\n]+` replace with `\r\n`

Comment: It is actually `/\s*\n\s*/g` or `/\s*[\r\n]\s*/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/(?: *[\n\r])+ */`:

- `*[\n\r]` matches literal white space followed by a new line character;
- use `+` to match one or more consecutive *whitespace + new line characters*;
- use `*` to match zero or more white spaces at the end of pattern;

```js
var s = "Hello,     \n\r  \n\n\n \n      World \n\n     ! \n A new line";

console.log(s);

console.log(s.replace(/(?: *[\n\r])+ */g, '\n'));
```